# "This content is currently unavailable" in facebook notifications after tagging user in comments plugin

Tags: facebook, comments

We use facebook comments plugin on our site. 
And each time you write a comment and tag user in it he gets email with a link to the broken comment thread "This content is currently unavailable".

What do I need to do to resolve this? Can I do anything?